# VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I am trying to connect Azure DevOps using below code in asp.net core(2.1) mvc app

```
Uri orgUrl = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/");          
String personalAccessToken = "xxxxx";  
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));
```

But getting this error `"VssUnauthorizedException: 'VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.'"`

**Same code is working in .net core console app**, Please can anybody help me on this?

Here my code i am trying to get Work items, geting error on GetClient 
[image]

Comment: How the things going? Does your MVC app can execute successfully now? Feel free to share us your process thus other SO users can help you.

Answer (score 7):

There's no error on your code.

> VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.

This is an unauthorized error code. It should caused by your PAT token is not available. By using your code, if I use a expired token, will receive the same error.

[image]

After generated a new PAT token, the error disappeared and the code work successfully.

So, just try with generate a new token from Azure Devops and use it.

**Updated:**

With the key code which from the screenshot of the updated question, I create a completed Application to writeLine the WIQL result. Still succeed shown as below:

[image]

Could you execute your code and share the error screenshot?(Note: Just for error line)

Comment: Thanks, but new PAT is also giving same issue and old one is not expired. Interesting thing is same code is working in console app for both new and old PAT, so i am not able to figure out why it is not working in web app?

Comment: I could not know what's your script look like. See my updated pic in answer, it still succeed on my Asp.Net core mvc app with the same code and same token. No difference used between Console app and Asp.Net core MVC app.Do you mind share which operation(API) are you trying to doing? Better share some code.

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshot of code please have a look

Comment: @nakul89 I don't know how do you list and writeLine the result of WIQL. But I use the code which shown in your updated screenshots to create a complete application, still succeed. See the updated pic in my answer. It's weird and I think the error should not caused by these credential connection script. Emm~~You'd better share more so that I could debug it.

Comment: Here is my code https://github.com/ncool89/vsts.git ,can you please check what is wrong in that?

Comment: @nakul89 I tested and analysis these code, very wired that it’s succeed on my side.( I test with disabling the code related to sql connect). Since console app has cache, you’d better change another machine to compile these script.

Comment: @nakul89 In addition, you can use fiddler to capture the data between this mvc app and azure devops. In fiddler trace you can see the detailed error about 401 caused reason. Fiddler is a very great debug tool between web applicant and internet

Comment: @IngoB Could you try with using Fiddler to capture the internet records? Or you can raise a new ticket with the fiddler trace if convenient.

Comment: @Merlin Liang: It was my wrong, see my answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was caused by a wrong organization URL.

When you use a URL like this:

```http
https://dev.azure.com/example-org
```

And the organization exists but you do not have access to `example-org`, then you will also get the message:

```
VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but with DevOps Server. You must provide not only the server url, but the org/collection as well!

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the PAT permissions on every scope you are using? After creating a new token, I forgot to set permissions on "Code" - "read" for the GitHttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while setting up self-hosted build agents in an existing Azure DevOps project. The issue persisted even after being added to the `Project Administrators` group.

The solution was to add permissions to the Agent Pools at the *organisation* level settings. Adding permissions at the project level are insufficient - my guess is this is because agent pools are shared across projects within an Azure DevOps organisation.

[image: screenshot of azure devops organisation settings. agent pool blade is highlighted]

Answer (score -1):

I got this error while creating custom agent in azure devops after entering the PAT.
I gave full control while creating new PAT and used that PAT while configuring custom agent pool.

[image]

Comment: What subset of permissions is required to create/query work items? I'm getting this error with full access to work items